# Survival Analysis with multiple time series and intervention events

Tags: r, time-series, survival

I have data in a longitudinal format that I would like to analyze. A sample of My data looks like this in R:

```
   ID Location Type            DateTime Test    Result
    8        4    6 2016-10-01 04:14:19    4    8.2000
    8        4    6 2016-10-01 04:14:19   11   32.0000
    8        4    6 2016-10-01 15:54:25    4    7.6000
    8        4    6 2016-10-01 15:54:25   11   31.0000
    8        4    6 2016-10-02 04:03:04    4    7.9000
    8        4    6 2016-10-02 04:03:04   11   33.0000
    8        4    6 2016-10-02 15:59:00    4    7.6000
    8        4    6 2016-10-02 15:59:00   11   30.0000
    ....
    8        4    6 2016-10-17 10:23:21   12 3000.0000
    8        4    6 2016-10-17 10:28:38    4    7.6000
    8        4    6 2016-10-17 10:28:38   11   32.0000
    8        4    6 2016-10-17 11:13:45    6   31.8000
    8        4    6 2016-10-17 14:26:23    6   31.9000
    8        4    6 2016-10-18 04:32:34    4    7.8000
    ....
    8        4    6 2016-10-20 15:50:26    9  240.0000
    8        4    6 2016-10-20 15:50:26   11   40.0000
    8        4    6 2016-10-21 04:34:27    4    7.4000
    ....
```

Tests 4 and 11 are recorded almost daily. These are purely observational. Tests 1, 2, 3, 6, and 8 are also purely observational, but not conducted on a regular basis. Only when something is suspected to be wrong based on the results of test 4 and 11. The tests that cause an intervention in the system are tests 7, 9, and 12. A failure is considered when the result of test 9 is greater than or equal to 240.

I am interested in knowing two questions. Does the intervention tests extend the life of the series? At a given point in time how much longer can I expect my series to last? I think survival analysis would be able to answer these questions, but I do not have much experience in this branch of modeling. Am I on the correct path here or is a different approach required?

If survival analysis is the right path the hurdle I am running into is the structure of my data. Every example I've seen uses aggregation of the time stamped data into a structure like this:

```
seriesID startTime EndTime death test1Indicator test2Indicator
```

My problem is that not only is the presence of a test in a series important, but so is the value of that test. I have not found an example of survival analysis with continuous multivariate event data. I appreciate any and all thoughts and thanks for reading my lengthy post.